# Bootstrap carousel, how to update left and right glypicon with font awesome arrows

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I want to use the font awesome arrows with the code given in w3schools tut because glypicons aren't supported anymore and I can't get

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>New York</h3>
        <p>The atmosphere in New York is lorem ipsum.</p>
      </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Chicago</h3>
        <p>Thank you, Chicago - A night we won't forget.</p>
      </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>LA</h3>
        <p>Even though the traffic was a mess, we had the best time.</p>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

in the right and left control I have tried changing it to the font awesome arrows but can't get it to work.